# Get an application, to ask for automation permissions?

Tags: macos, preferences

[image]

How can I force an app to ask for automation permissions? [image]

So that I can make it have permissions to access documents and data in safari.

Like this [image]

But for safari.

Answer (score 2):

You can't manually 'force' one app to control another: Safari has to allow the control, and Cubox Helper needs to ask for it.

It's possible that Safari's security prevents access; it might be that Cubox needs to support Safari.

Ask the developer if it's possible.